# Как объединить данные?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, excel, csv, matlab

> В базе данных хранятся архивные данные 2 параметров в виде `временная метка : значение`.
> Временная метка имеет формат "2020-06-08 11:45:21.847".
> Построить графики зависимости значений параметров от времени легко.

Но попросили построить график зависимости одного параметра от другого.

Здравый смысл подсказывает взять значения обоих параметров в один момент времени и построить 3-осевой график.

Но я не знаю как объединить 2 файла в один.

Пример.

Файл №1.

```
2020-06-08 11:45:21.847  2.3  
2020-06-08 11:45:22.147  2.4  
2020-06-08 11:45:22.847  2.4  
2020-06-08 11:45:23.127  2.3  
2020-06-08 11:45:24.007  2.4
```

Файл №2.

```
2020-06-08 11:45:21.865  203  
2020-06-08 11:45:22.197  204  
2020-06-08 11:45:24.027  237
```

То есть можно объединить временные метки в один ряд. И вставить нужные значения в соответствующие места.

Пример.

```
2020-06-08 11:45:21.847  2.3 ---  
2020-06-08 11:45:21.865  --- 203  
2020-06-08 11:45:22.147  2.4 ---  
2020-06-08 11:45:22.197  --- 204   
2020-06-08 11:45:22.847  2.4 ---    
2020-06-08 11:45:23.127  2.3 ---   
2020-06-08 11:45:24.007  2.4 ---    
2020-06-08 11:45:24.027  --- 237
```

Затем логически вставить предыдущие значения.

Но делать это вручную с 31тысячей записей как то не рационально.

Написать формулу в Excel смогу. В Python наверное смогу написать несложный проект. В Matlab вроде умею что-то, а вроде и нет. Толкните меня в каком нибудь направлении.

Жду вопросов и предложений.

Спасибо за комментарии. Комментарий про excel натолкнул на мысль.
В общем сделал все в Matlab:

1. Через утилиту импорт закидываем нужные данные. Получаем тип данных table.
2. Преобразуем table в timetable командой table2timetable
3. Объединяем таблицы с помощью команды synchronize.

Естественно читаем справку по командам и поисковые системы в помощь по непонятным вопросам.
Ну а дальше уже строите графики и анализируете данные

Comment: Вручную-то зачем? В Экселе это делается за две минуты автоматом. Вставить первую таблицу, добавить пустой столбец между датами и значениями, вставить первую таблицу ниже (значения получатся в разных столбцах). И построить сводную таблицу (или сразу построить график - точечный). Всё.

Comment: На Pandas (модуль Python) это делается в несколько строк. Для этого данные агрегируются с точностью до минуты и берётся среднее значение. Это позволит объединить две таблицы по времени. график зависимости одного параметра от другого - проще всего построить 2D. По X - один параметр, по Y - другой.